# I can't proper recover a WSL backup using export/import

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, backup, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

So, I just created and restored a WSL2 backup using the export and import commands.
But after I imported the backup, although all the files are there, it looks like I lost all the "environment" installed stuff.

For example, rbenv/ruby was not installed, tsh(teleporte), basically nothing that I had installed before I created the backup, was installed after I recoved it.

Backup created on: Windows 11, i7-11800H, 32GB RAM
Restored on: Windows 10, i5-7300Q, 16Gb RAM
WSL2 on both systems.

Is this the expected behaviour or I did something wrong?